# How to properly set `baseReserve` & `baseFee` to 0

Tags: transactions, fees

I ran a basic private network with the line `COMMANDS=["upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z&basefee=0&basereserve=0"]` inside of my `stellar-core.cfg` file on **all** of my nodes (5 of them), so I'm expecting the network to treat all transactions with 0 `baseFee` and 0 `baseReserve`. However, when I run `stellar-core --c info`, I can see that `baseFee=100` and `baseReserve=100000000` under `ledger`, which I'm assuming is the default amount. So either that the command I ran didn't get applied correctly or there is a difference between the ledger's `baseFee` and `baseReserve`. What's going on?

Comment: This may be of interest - I’m not sure if it is still the case but you can try it with 1 to see if it works https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/1594

Comment: Well the OP of that issue says he's getting a `[default INFO] could not parse basereserve: '0' Failed to parse 'basereserve' argument` error which I'm not getting, but who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paul was right in the sense that you can't set the base reserve to 0. change it to 1 and it worked.